# Apache 2.4 Error Log entries incomplete

Tags: django, apache, logging, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am trying to configure Apache 2.4 to include log ID (%L) and remote client IP(%a) into the error.log entries  so that I can correlate log entries from multiple log files. It works for every log entry, but not for the most important one - mod_wsgi (my Django app)

This is the logging conf. from Virtual Host

```
LogLevel debug

ErrorLogFormat "[LogID %-L] [Remote IP %-a] [%-m:%l] [pid %P:tid %T] %M% ,\   referer\ %{Referer}i"
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/forensic.log" mylog
```

This is the error.log output

```
[LogID -] [Remote IP -] [wsgi:error] [pid 24298:tid 140284674643712][04/Aug/2016 14:50:38] [myapp:common:66] INFO -- Some info message
[LogID wYeHZQ5DK5k] [Remote IP <SHOWN_HERE>:58713] [deflate:debug] [pid 24300:tid 140284649465600] AH01384: Zlib: Compressed 12502 to 3121 : URL /, referer http://myapp.com/
```

So the problem is that the LogId and Remote (client) IP are not shown for any log entry comming from wsgi, but as you can see in the second line it works for other modules....

Any help is appreciated!

UPDATE:

Here is the wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: What mod_wsgi version are you using? Are you using mod_wsgi daemon mode? My guess would be that you might be using daemon mode. Stuff has to be fudged up to get logging to work at all in daemon mode, so maybe something is missing in the way that is done.

Comment: Hi Graham, I am using 4.3.0-1 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 (obtained form dpkg). I am using daemon mode with threaded event MPM (this was inspired by your blog post actually :)) The logging is working by as shown above some parts are missing. Any idea how to fix this? If you need more info. please let me know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'll have to run some tests myself to validate it. I suspect you likely have found an issue in mod_wsgi with that daemon mode configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much! Please let me know if you find something.

Comment: I have just added the wsgi.py (to the original question), since I believe it might come in handy to compare with your tests...

Comment: What is the '-' after the '%' for in the format for? Using that '-' causes my Apache to choke on the configuration file with an error.

Comment: That is the "default" value to show if the actual value is not supplied. You can remove it won't change anything.

Comment: For a start, if something if just logging to ``sys.stdout`` or ``sys.stderr`` it cannot be correlated back to the specific request. In that case there can't be any log id or remote client information. The only way that information could be associated with a request would be log messages via the per request ``environ['wsgi.errors']``. That at least does work for embedded mode, but doesn't work for daemon mode for the log id at least. The only way to have it work for ``sys.stdout`` or ``sys.stderr`` would be to modify mod_wsgi to reach back to thread local with current request for thread.

Comment: So needs to be fixed for ``environ['wsgi.errors']`` and would need to look at whether possible to make it work in reasonable way for global (non request specific) ``sys.stdout`` and ``sys.stderr``.

Comment: Two issues created https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/144 and https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/145

Comment: Thanks for dealing with this so promptly! I suspected that the request context gets lost when the worker threads are spawned, thus causing the loss of remote client IP, log ID, etc information. Now I have another related question which I posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786532/logging-with-apache-2-4-mod-wsgi-and-django).