# Logging with Apache 2.4, mod_wsgi and Django

Tags: django, apache, logging, mod-wsgi

Is there a way to configure the logging with mod_wsgi and Django without losing the request information, such as remote client IP or unique log ID AND without using `environ['wsgi.errors']`?

I have been trying out different logging configurations for different mod_wsgi modes. I have found out that in daemon mode there is an issue which causes some logging information (related to request context) to get lost ([see this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767989/apache-2-4-error-log-entries-incomplete)). This should however work in embedded mode (only prefork MPM?) and `environ['wsgi.errors']`. Nevertheless, I think it is a bad idea to make my applications logging dependent on the mod_wsgi...

If there is currently no way around using `environ['wsgi.errors']` variable, is there a drop-in replacement/wrapper for Django logging middleware that can be used?

Comment: It would be better to bring this over to the mod_wsgi mailing list for further discussion. No one here will be able to help you and the mailing list is a better place to discuss issues.

Comment: Since in my opinion this should be a fairly common (and important) case, I thought that maybe there is some nice solution, e.g., wrapper that somebody already implemented. OK, I will bring this also to the mailing list.

Comment: All these issues are fixed for version 4.5.4 of mod_wsgi.

Comment: I cannot get the code for 4.5.4 of mod_wsgi. The link provided in the GitHub release notes is 404.

Comment: Version 4.5.4 is not released yet. As was mentioned on the mod_wsgi mailing list the changes are on develop branch in repo. I have been waiting for you to test and confirm works as expected before releasing.

Comment: I have released 4.5.4 now, but it would be very much appreciated if you can still reply via the mailing list confirming it does work and doesn't cause problems. If there are problems will need to revert change or fix any issue caused.

Comment: The changes you were after are being reported as causing problems. This is why it is important as the person who wanted it that you do test the changes and report success or otherwise so problems can be caught before it is released. Changes may have to be rolled back as it isn't obvious why at this point it is failing.

Comment: I  provided the comments in the mailing list explaining the issue.